# Calculating area under the curves

Tags: python

I am attempting to calculate the area of the blue region and the area of yellow region:
In this graph: y=blue, peak_line=green, thresh=orange.

[image: Image1]

I am using this code:

```
idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(y - peak_line))).flatten()
bounds = [1077.912, 1078.26, 1078.336, 1078.468, 1078.612, 1078.78, 1078.828, 1078.88, 1079.856, 1079.86]
plt.plot(x, y, x, thresh, x, peak_line)
plt.fill_between(x, y, thresh, where=(y>=peak_line),interpolate=True, color='#fff8ba')
plt.fill_between(x, thresh, peak_line, where=(y<=peak_line),interpolate=True, color='#fff8ba')
plt.fill_between(x, y, peak_line, where=(y>=peak_line) & (x>=x[idx][0]) & (x<=bounds[-1]), interpolate=True, color='#CDEAFF')
plt.plot(x[idx], y[idx], 'ro')
plt.show()

estimated_y = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')
estimated_peak_line = interp1d(x, peak_line, kind='cubic')
estimated_thresh = interp1d(x, thresh, kind='cubic')

yellow_areas = []
blue_areas = []
for i in range(len(bounds) - 1):
    midpoint = (bounds[i] + bounds[i+1]) / 2
    if estimated_y(midpoint) < estimated_peak_line(midpoint):
        above_peak_line = abs(integrate.quad(estimated_peak_line, bounds[i], bounds[i+1])[0])
        above_thresh_line = abs(integrate.quad(estimated_thresh, bounds[i], bounds[i+1])[0])
        yellow_areas.append(above_peak_line - above_thresh_line)

    else:
        above_peak_line = abs(integrate.quad(estimated_peak_line, bounds[i], bounds[i+1])[0])
        above_y = abs(integrate.quad(estimated_y, bounds[i], bounds[i+1])[0])
        blue_areas.append(above_peak_line - above_y)

print(sum(yellow_areas))
print(sum(blue_areas))
4.900000000000318
2.999654602006661
```

I thought I calculated the area of the blue region and the area of yellow region correct, until I calculated the area of the polygon:

```
bunch_of_xs = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), num=10000, endpoint=True)
final_curve = estimated_y(bunch_of_xs)
final_thresh = estimated_thresh(bunch_of_xs)
final_peak_line = estimated_peak_line(bunch_of_xs)

def PolygonArea(corners):
    n = len(corners) # of corners
    area = 0.0
    for i in range(n):
        j = (i + 1) % n
        area += corners[i][0] * corners[j][1]
        area -= corners[j][0] * corners[i][1]
    area = abs(area) / 2.0
    return area

vertex1 = (bunch_of_xs[0], final_thresh[0])
vertex2 = (bunch_of_xs[-1], final_thresh[-1])
vertex3 = (x[idx][-1], y[idx][-1])
vertex4 = (x[idx][0], y[idx][0])
coords = (vertex1,vertex2,vertex3,vertex4)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', bunch_of_xs, final_curve, '--', bunch_of_xs, final_thresh, bunch_of_xs, final_peak_line)
x_val = [x[0] for x in coords]
y_val = [x[1] for x in coords]
plt.plot(x_val,y_val,'or')
print("Coordinates of total polygon:", coords)
print("Total polygon area:", PolygonArea(coords))
Coordinates of total polygon: ((1077.728, -41.30177170550451), (1079.96, -42.254314285935834), (1079.86, -49.207348695828706), (1077.912, -48.271572477115136))
Total polygon area: 14.509708069890621
```

[image: Image2]

The sum of the area of the blue region and the area of yellow region should equal the total polygon area.

4.900000000000318 + 2.999654602006661 ≠ 14.509708069890621

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: This code will be used for many different graphs. Not all graphs look the same. For example, this graph has 3 blue regions and so I have to calculate the area of all 3 blue regions and add them together to get the total blue area. Every graph has a different amount of blue regions (some only have 1 region). So, I have to make the code flexible to account for the possibility of a graph having multiple blue regions to add together to get the total blue region area.

Comment: Hi, Is there a special reason why you don't use any built bumpy functions like np.trapz? If I were you, implementing integration myself is not something I would do.

Comment: @יונתןשוומנטל Hi, I did it this way because this code will be used for many different graphs. Not all graphs look the same. For example, this graph has 3 blue regions and so I have to calculate the area of all 3 blue regions and add them together to get the total blue area. Every graph has a different amount of blue regions (some only have 1 region). So, I have to make the code flexible to account for the possibility of a graph having multiple blue regions to add together.

Comment: Given the crossing points, you could iterate over the three different areas, and sum of np.trapz over each one. It seems like you already have the intersection points, so it is supposed to be straightforward. I think that using np.trapz is more flexible than implementing you own code.

Comment: @יונתןשוומנטל Thanks for your feedback. Would you mind submitting an answer with the np.trapz implementation? I am struggling to see how that would work with the code I provided.

Comment: Why does the first and last part of the graph (before the first intersection of the blue and green lines and after the last intersection) not count towards the area of the blue line above the green line?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi It is a requirement that region before the first intersection of the blue and green lines AND the region after the last intersection of the blue and green lines is not included. That is why I included "(x>=x[idx][0]) & (x<=bounds[-1])" as apart of the where statement in plt.fill_between.

Comment: can you provide data for your curves?

Comment: @AjayVerma How can I do that because when I try to add the data to the original question it says I have too many characters?

Comment: Why do you expect the sum of the blue and yellow regions will equal the area of the polygon? You explicitly excluded [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq3Fd.png) area from your calculation, and that is part of the polygon, is it not? Unless by area of the polygon you meant [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2wIh.png) one, in which case it still won't be equal because the curves along the sides of the "polygon" aren't straight lines.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Hi, yes I did mean [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2wIh.png). I just figured that since the area of that polygon is 14.5, we would want the blue and yellow area to add up somewhat close to 14.5. I know that area calculation isn't exact because the curves along the sides aren't straight lines, but I imagined we would want the sum of the yellow region and the blue region to be somewhat close to 14.5. Right now in my code, the sum of these regions is 8. Am I incorrect with this logic?

Comment: No your logic sounds right, the only reason I can think of that the difference is so huge is that one of the areas isn't calculated correctly. Did you try to adapt the code from [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64127530/843953) to your needs? Maybe try using a simpler curve, like a straight line or a couple of straight lines or something, to debug?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi yes, I did. It seems like the result of the blue region is correct. Now just need to figure out how to calculate the yellow region correctly.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the area between two curves `f(x)` and `g(x)` is `integral(g(x) - f(x))`.

So say we have two curves:

```
xvals = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
yvals_1 = np.sin(xvals * 10)
yvals_2 = 0.5 - 0.5 * xvals

plt.plot(xvals, yvals_1, '-b')
plt.plot(xvals, yvals_2, '-g')
```

[image]

The "transformed" curve becomes:

```
yvals_3 = yvals_1 - yvals_2
plt.plot(xvals, yvals_3, '--r')
plt.plot(xvals, np.zeros(xvals.shape), '--k')
```

And since we want to ignore everything under the green line,

```
yvals_3[yvals_3 < 0] = 0
plt.plot(xvals, yvals_3, '-r')
```

[image]

Since you want to impose additional constraints, such as "only the area between the first and last intersections", do that now.

```
# Cheating a little bit -- but you already know how to get the intersections.
first_intersection_x = xvals[4]
last_intersection_x = xvals[94]

cfilter = np.logical_and(xvals >= first_intersection_x, xvals <= last_intersection_x)
xvals_calc = xvals[cfilter]
yvals_calc = yvals_3[cfilter]
```

The area under this curve is easily calculated using [`np.trapz`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html)

```
area_under_curve = np.trapz(yvals_calc, xvals_calc)
```

Of course, this answer assumes that `yvals_1` and `yvals_2` are available at the same `xvals`. If not, [interpolation is easy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html).

Comment: When I ran your code, my result was 3.000263748958751. My result was for the area of the blue region was 2.999654602006661. I am now confident that the blue region is calculated correctly.. now just need to figure out how to calculate the yellow region.

Comment: @dfahsjdahfsudaf that is also quite easy. Yellow area = area under the yellow curve - area under the purple curve, i.e. max of the blue + green [(See this plot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVBKF.png). `g(x)` is the yellow curve, `f(x) = max(p(x), q(x))` where `p(x)` is the lower line and `q(x)` is the squiggly curve

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't have all of your data I will give something between pseudo-code and implementation.
Say we have arrays `x` (x-axis), `y1` (data), `y2` (some line which bounds the parts over which we want to integrate).

First step: Iterate over your bounds array and see which parts we want to integrate over. I assume that you have the bounds array already, as your question suggests.

```
def get_pairs_of_idxs(x, y1, y2, bounds):
    lst_pairs = []
    for i in range(len(bounds)-1):
        x0, x1 = bounds[i], bounds[i+1]
        xc = 0.5 * (x0 + x1) # we want to see if the straight line y2 is above or below, so we take one x value and test it
        indx_xc = np.searchsorted(x, xc) # this returns us the index at which xc is located
        y1c, y2c = y1[indx_xc], y2[indx_xc]
        if y2c < y1c: # then the line is below the curve, so we want to integrate
            lst_pairs.append((x0, x1))
```

Now we have a list of pairs of indices, between which we want to integrate.

```
def solution(x, y1, y2, bounds):
     tot_area = 0
     lst_pairs = get_pairs_of_idxs(x, y1, y2, bounds)
     for x0, x1 in lst_pairs:
          mask = np.logical_and(x >= x0, x <= x1) # relevant places in x and y data
          xs = x[mask] # the x values along which we integrate
          ys = (y2 - y1)[mask] # we want to integrate the difference of the curves
          tot_area += np.trapz(ys, xs)
     return tot_area
```

That's what I was thinking about.

Comment: Good answer. It outputted 2.99965460200666, which is the same result that I got for the area of the blue region with my code. How would you then find the area of the yellow region?

Comment: You can do so by calculating the area between green and orange lines (using simple np.trapz), and reduct the blue are which you already calculated.